# looking if String contain a sub-string in differents Dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes:

df_1, column `id` contain only characters and numbers ==> normalized, and `id_no_normalized`
Example:

```
 id_normalized   |  id_no_normalized
    -------------|-------------------
    ABC          |  A_B.C
    -------------|-------------------
    ERFD         |  E.R_FD
    -------------|-------------------
    12ZED        |   12_Z.ED
```

df_2, column `name`  contain only characters and numbers ==> normalized are attached

Example:

```
name
----------------------------
googleisa12ZEDgoodnavigator
----------------------------
internetABCexplorer
----------------------------
```

I would like to look the `id_normalized (dataset_1)` if exist in `name (dataset_2)`. If I find it, I take the value of `id_no_normalized` and I store it in a new column in `dataset_2`

Expect result:

```
   name                         |   result
    ----------------------------|----------
    googleisa12ZEDgoodnavigator |  12_Z.ED
    ----------------------------|----------
    internetABCexplorer         |  A_B.C
    ----------------------------|----------
```

I did it using this code:

```
df_result = df_2.withColumn("id_no_normalized", dft_2.name.contains(df_1.id_normalized))
    return df_result.select("name", "id_normalized")
```

is not working because, it doesn't find the `id_normalized` in the df_2.

```
Second solution, it work only when I limited the output on 300 rows almost, but when I return all the data, is took many time running and not finish:

   df_1 = df_1.select("id_no_normalized").drop_duplicates()
df_1 = df_1.withColumn(
    "id_normalized",
    F.regexp_replace(F.col("id_no_normalized"), "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", ""))
df_2 = df_2.select("name")
extract = F.expr('position(id_normalized IN name)>0')
result = df_1.join(df_2, extract)
return result
```

How can I correct my code to resolve it ?
Thank you

Comment: There is no easy way to do what you are asking efficiently. This type of join will result in a Cartesian product, which will be slow. See [Efficient string suffix detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54481681/efficient-string-suffix-detection) and [Efficient string matching in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938672/efficient-string-matching-in-apache-spark)

Comment: How many unique `id_normalized` do you have?

Comment: @pault  thanks for your answer. In fact, I succeeded to join the 2 datasets, my idea was to use monotonically_increasing_id() function in each datasaet then I joined them using the new colunm that contain the monotonically_increasing_id values as key. I asked a new question if you can help me please knowing that I used spark version < 2.4. Thank you. my question is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59228817/extract-string-from-text-pyspark

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this using cross join and applying UDF on new DF, but again we need to ensure it works on a big dataset.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

data1 = [
 {"id_normalized":"ABC","id_no_normalized":"A_B.C"},
 {"id_normalized":"ERFD","id_no_normalized":"E.R_FD"},
 {"id_normalized":"12ZED","id_no_normalized":"12_Z.ED"}
]

data2 = [
 {"name": "googleisa12ZEDgoodnavigator"},
 {"name": "internetABCexplorer"}
]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, ["id_no_normalized", "id_normalized"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, ["name"])

df3 = df1.crossJoin(df2)
search_for_udf = udf(lambda name,id_normalized: name.find(id_normalized), returnType=IntegerType())
df4 = df3.withColumn("contain", search_for_udf(df3["name"], df3["id_normalized"]))
df4.filter(df4["contain"] > -1).show()


>>> df4.filter(df4["contain"] > -1).show()
+----------------+-------------+--------------------+-------+
|id_no_normalized|id_normalized|                name|contain|
+----------------+-------------+--------------------+-------+
|           A_B.C|          ABC| internetABCexplorer|      8|
|         12_Z.ED|        12ZED|googleisa12ZEDgoo...|      9|
+----------------+-------------+--------------------+-------+
```

I believe there are some spark techniques available to make cross join efficient.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, you already mentioned, I need to ensure it works on a big dataset. I think, the problem is because I'm working on a big data

Comment: not this result I expect, see my question above please. Thanks